# custom round skin gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

In looking for a starting place to how to create a round interface. I have tried looking into the docs and tried looking into other plugins for Eclipse. I'm just starting to build gui's with java and everything I find is either asking for me to be a part of a company to use their product or want a few hundred dollars.

I'm just a humble coder trying my hand at gui's and a personal project I'm working on wants a round gui skin.

Comment: *"round interface"*....?  What does that mean?

Comment: What I mean by round is that I don't want the square/rectangular window. I an wanting an interface that is in a circle.

Comment: *"I'm just starting to build gui's with java.."*  Steer clear of non-rectangular GUIs for a long while yet.  They are effectively an 'expert' topic and have very limited use, and learning how to layout (even) a rectangular GUI is itself a steep learning curve for some.

Answer (score 4):

There are, at least, two ways you might achieve this...

### You could...

Use [`JFrame#setShape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape(java.awt.Shape)) to alter the shape of the main window, for example...

[image: Circle Frame]

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
frame.add(new JLabel("Boo!"));
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200));
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is simple, but frankly, looks crap.  There's no way to implement soft clipping to smooth out the edges with this technique...

### You could...

Create a transparent window and "fake" the shape...

[image: Circle]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CircleUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CircleUI();
    }

    public CircleUI() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new CirclePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CirclePane extends JPanel {

        public CirclePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Boo!"));
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Which, arguably, produces a nicer looking result, but will allow you to display components beyond the shape (allow them to overflow), so you need to be able to manage the content to ensure that this doesn't happen...

### You could...

Do both...

[image: Circle]

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// This is the secret here...
JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
content.setOpaque(false);
content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
content.add(new CirclePane());

frame.setContentPane(content);
frame.pack();
int width = frame.getWidth();
int height = frame.getHeight();
frame.setShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, width, height));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

What this does is uses the `setShape` method from the first example, with the soft clipping from the second example and combines them.  This is done by using another `JPanel` to act as the container for our "fake" shape panel and supplying a very small (1 pixel) empty border.  This pushes the size of the frame out from the edge of our soft clipping panel, but means that any components that overflow it, will be clipped...

Comment: *"Create a transparent window and "fake" the shape... Which, arguably, produces a nicer looking result, but will allow you to display components beyond the shape (allow them to overflow).."* You might combine that with a slightly larger clip as in your first example then add an `EmptyBorder` to the content pane to ensure the content is within the solid colored area of the 2nd example.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Shhhh....how am I suppose to "wow" people with my apparent "brilliance" if you keep telling them all the secrets...

Answer (score 0):

Call the setOpacity method on your JFrame. More details here:
http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-create-shaped-jframes-in-java.html

Other options for Java 6 and Java 7: [click here for examples in another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935558/java-rounded-corners-on-jframe)

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(frame, new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

If you really want to learn Java GUI's, you should spend some time studying AWT, Swing, or JavaFX, the core Java libraries for doing GUI work, and basic objects like `JFrame` and `JWindow`, and creating menus, buttons, `ActionListener`s and layouts.