# Crop image by polygon area in Java

Tags: java, canvas, crop

by using Canvas and JS I can draw a shape like this and have the x,y of each point :
[image]

Tha area can be choosen by more than 4 points, look at this [link](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?FahE34Ft) to have an idea.

I need to save and crop the image of the selected area by using the points. I can not use `BufferedImage` as it is just rectangular. Which lib in java I can use?

Comment: Well, the image is always s going to be rectangular, you could use the points to generate a shape and use them to generate a clipping area to paint the image into, but as I said, the result will always be a rectangular image, just with what you've selected and what ever background color you've decided to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so starting with...

[image: Your original image]

I used...

```
BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("Example.jpg"));
GeneralPath clip = new GeneralPath();
clip.moveTo(65, 123);
clip.lineTo(241, 178);
clip.lineTo(268, 405);
clip.lineTo(145, 512);
clip.closePath();

Rectangle bounds = clip.getBounds();
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(bounds.width, bounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
clip.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-65, -123));
g2d.setClip(clip);
g2d.translate(-65, -123);
g2d.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();

ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Clipped.png"));
```

to generate...

[image: Clipped]

Now, the image is rectangular, that's just the way it works

Now, `setClip` is quite rough and isn't effect by any `RenderingHints`, you could make use of "soft clipping" instead, which is more involved, but generates a nicer results.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423130/how-to-make-circle-image-label-in-java/31424601#31424601) and [this exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394366/custom-round-skin-gui/25395267#25395267) for more details

Comment: Thank you, but What if I choose 5 or 6 points instead of 4, on that case  i can not use "Rectangle" bounds!

Comment: Look at this to see what it might happen if you choose more than 4 points : http://www.jqueryrain.com/?FahE34Ft

Comment: @Majico You can use as many points as you like and still use `getBounds`, but you might want to look into `Rectangle#getMinX/Y` and `Rectangle#getMaxX/Y`

Comment: Thanks for your complate solution, it works like a charm! :)