# how to crop image shape in Hexagon,Octagon or rectangle shape

Tags: java, image-processing, javafx-8, crop, fxml

I want to crop image shape in Hexagon,Octagon or rectangle shape.the image is on imageView and the Coordinates of vertices are given by user on mouse click. 
how can i crop image of imageView according to given coordinate.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty

Comment: i am beginner can you please give me a example code that uses Polygon

Comment: please read [ask]. this is not a coding service and we don't provide tutorials either. try to solve the problem yourself. take small steps and once you fail at a particular step you can show what you have done so far and many people will love to help you overcome that hurdle so you can proceed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541086/crop-image-by-polygon-area-in-java]